# Hiding certain records and their related records

Tags: custom-object, administration, record, org-wide-defaults

I am trying to keep records separate from certain users when it is categorized in a specific group. For instance, when an account is created if it's in category A I want only group A to have access to the record. Also if it does not have a category, everyone should have access to the account. Right now I have the org-wide default set to private and a sharing rule on account reading off of a picklist. The problem I am running into is the related records. If an account is category A, anyone not in Group A, should not be able to see the related records.

I have considered making a process builder update a field on all the related records and have sharing rules on all the objects. But there has to be a more efficient way. Once the parent account is shared with a group or all users the related records should be shared as well. I have thought about making a custom role hierarchy but I don't think that solves the related custom object records.

Comment: Only master-detail relationships inherit sharing. Lookup relationships do not.

Comment: Correct, but it wouldn't make sense to add a master-detail to every custom object. I think that would make it harder for users to create records then the process builder. There has to be a workaround for this.

Comment: There is a workaround, it's the one you mentioned in your question or similar approaches. Lookup relationships are limited and I don't expect that will ever change. That's why tools Like DLRS exist.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can create a formula field on child objects (related list) to identify the category of parent record and sharing rule similar to the one you've created before.

Comment: Unfortunately, sharing rules cannot read off of a formula field.

Comment: Or a custom field and get it auto-populated using a process builder or trigger.

Comment: Yes, in my post I referenced that option, but I'm looking for a workaround to prevent, spending the time to creating those fields and the process. The larger issue is after the process runs if someone creates a new related record how does that field update if the account isn't updated?